# Angle between two pairs of azimuth and altitude?

Tags: python, astronomy, pyephem

I have a solar panel pointing (it's normal vector) in some direction. I want to calculate the angle between that and the current position of the sun. I am using pyephem and I have this information in two pairs of azimuth and altitude.

```
panel_az = ephem.degrees('180')
panel_alt = ephem.degrees('45')
sun_az = ephem.degrees('245')
sun_alt = ephem.degrees('22')
```

What is the easiest way to find the angle between the panel's normal vector and the vector pointing towards the sun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The library offers a `separation()` function that gives the angle between two spherical coordinates; look near the bottom of this section of the Quick Reference:

http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html#other-functions

I think you will get the angle you are seeking if you run:

```
a = ephem.separation((panel_az, panel_alt), (sun_az, sun_alt))
print a
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Convert both to vectors first:

```
z = sin(altitude)
hyp = cos(altitude)
y = hyp*cos(azimuth)
x = hyp*sin(azimuth)
vector = (x,y,z)
```

Then calculate the angle between the vectors (say a and b) using cross and dot products.

```
angle = atan2(norm(cross(a,b)), dot(a,b))
```

For cross use:

```
def cross(a, b):
    c = [a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1],
         a[2]*b[0] - a[0]*b[2],
         a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]]
    return c
```

For dot use:

```
def dot(a, b):
    c = [ a[i] * b[i] for i in range(len(a)) ]
    return c
```

For norm use:

```
def norm(a):
    mag = sqrt(sum(a[i]*a[i] for i in range(len(a))))
    c = [ a[i]/mag  for i in range(len(a)) ]
    return c
```

Comment: I guess that works. I did smth similar before. However, I was hoping for a solution that would not require so much coding from my side. PyEphem is big, so I was hoping this could be calculated with some convenience functions. Also, SciPy is huge, so is it really necessary to write my own definition of cross, dot and norm?

Answer (score 0):

```
clear,clc,clf;
for n=[15 46 74 105 135 166 196 227 258 288 319 349];
delta=23.45*(sind(360*(284+n)/365));
phi=31.2;
omega=acosd(-tand(phi).*tand(delta));
omega1=-omega:0.1:omega;
alt=(sind(delta).*sind(phi))+(cosd(delta).*cosd(omega1).*cosd(phi));
alt1=asind(abs(alt))
azm=(cosd(delta).*sind(omega1))./cosd(alt);
azm1=asind(azm)
 plot(azm1,alt1,'b');hold on;
  end
grid on
xlabel('Solar Azimuth');ylabel('Solar altitude');
text(0,85,'noon')
hold off
```

Comment: This would benefit from some explanation instead of just a code dump.